# How to create radio button in Titanium Alloy?

Tags: titanium, titanium-mobile, titanium-alloy

How can we create a radio button and multi select button in Titanium Alloy framework? Are there any XML tags to create the same?

I tried adding code from your ref and from following link https://github.com/Lukic/TiRadioButtonGroup/blob/master/Resources/app.js Now I'm able to get the radio button. But there is an issue with formatting. Now I am getting radio button as shown in screen shot.

[image]

But there I am not able to see any label names as options in my screen shot. Also I tried multiple radio buttons but I get issues with styles. I need the the similar to follwing screenshot. How can I do that.

[image]

Answer (score -1, accepted):

This code creates a radio button group.  You could use it in your Alloy project, though it is not an Alloy Widget.  This link has a fully working classic example.

https://github.com/yozef/TiRadioButtonGroup

Since it is not an Alloy widget, I believe you need to do all of this through the index.js file.

Inside your project's app folder.  Copy the radioButtonActive.png and radioButton.png to assets/iphone and assets/android.

In your index.xml file, I usually do something like:

```
 <Alloy>
    <Window class="container">
        <View id="radioView" />
    </Window>
</Alloy>
```

index.js

```
var radioButton = require('tiRadioButton');

var radioGroup = radioButton.createGroup({
    groupId:1,
    width:119,
    height:34,
    layout:'horizontal',
    radioItemsValue:['One', 'Two', 'Three'],
    radioItemsPadding:10,
    radioItemsBackgroundSelectedImage:'radioButtonActive.png',
    radioItemsBackgroundImage:'radioButton.png',
    radioItemsWidth:33,
    radioItemsHeight:34
});

var headline3 = Ti.UI.createLabel({
    text:'Layout: vertical',
    color:'#fff',
    font:{fontSize:20,fontWeight:'Bold'},
    shadowColor:'#000',
    shadowOffset:{x:1,y:1},
    top:10,
    textAlign:'center'
});     

var button = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title:'Get value' 
});

button.addEventListener('singletap', function(e) {
    alert("Horizontal radioGroup selectedIdx: " + radioGroup.selectedValue);
});

$.radioView.add(radioGroup);
$.radioView.add(button);
$.index.open();
```

index.tss

```
".container": {
    backgroundColor:"white"
},
"Label": {
    width: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    height: Ti.UI.SIZE,
    color: "#000"
}
```

Comment: I tried that but the radio button UI is not showing. Please sow me one example

Comment: This is all the code I have in my test project I used.  Includes all the files I created and some instructions on taking files from the original classic project.  Expect to see a Get Value button that reads the 3 fields on a white screen.  These fields do not have labels, just the radio buttons.  You'll have to look at the radio button library to see if it handles labels.

Comment: I tried your code with vertical view. Now the radio buttons are showing. but the option labels are not showing and also when I tried to add multiple radio button question I'm getting issue with styles

Comment: I have updated my question please suggest me some answer

Comment: Though I accepted your answer the labels are not showing to me. Please help me that I need to display the options one, two and three . Please help me out.

Comment: updated as new question in following link please suggest the solution, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26672482/issue-with-displaying-the-radio-button-label-in-tianium

Comment: no, its not showing radio buttons in alloy, can you please help it more

Answer (score 1):

```
    Although titanium does not support the check box,radio button you could always fake the functionality here is custom check box and radio button for you

    var checkbox = Ti.UI.createButton({
    title: '',
    top: 10,
    right: 10,
    width: 30,
    height: 30,
    borderColor: '#666',
    borderWidth: 2,
    borderRadius: 3,
    backgroundColor: '#aaa',
    backgroundImage: 'none',
    color: '#fff',
    font:{fontSize: 25, fontWeight: 'bold'},
    value: false //value is a custom property in this casehere.
});

//Attach some simple on/off actions
checkbox.on = function() {
    this.backgroundColor = '#007690';
    this.title='\u2713';
    this.value = true;
};

checkbox.off = function() {
    this.backgroundColor = '#aaa';
    this.title='';
    this.value = false;
};

checkbox.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    if(false == e.source.value) {
        e.source.on();
    } else {
        e.source.off();
    }
});
```

Comment: Very nice little checkbox. Thanks. Will probably be more useful as a module/class, then it can be slightly more easily packaged and used as lib in any project. But amazed this is not the accepted answer.

Answer (score 0):

**No**,In **Titanium Alloy framework we have not any Object like Radio Button.** For this we have need to create a Function for handle like Radio Button. 
**for example**, 
we can take 4 buttons and set Image like Radio button Image(non Selected).
 
 When we click on any one button then change button it **button image with Select Radio Button**. and **update all remain button image with Non-selected** images. Logically.

Thanks,

Comment: Just a clarification.  I believe the reason that Titanium Alloy doesn't have it, is because the IOS development tools don't natively support it either.  Titanium is mapping functionality to the native capabilities.

Comment: @Martin radio button is on iOS called Switch button which is supported by Titanium.